# ESP8266 GPIO 16 cannot be used as a button

Tags: c, mongoose-os

I have the following code, but I cannot see any log message:

```
void gpio_int_cb(int pin, void *arg) {
    LOG(LL_INFO, ("button pushed"));
    (void) pin;
    (void) arg;
}

extern "C" enum mgos_app_init_result mgos_app_init(void) {

    int pin_button = 16;

    mgos_gpio_set_pull(pin_button, MGOS_GPIO_PULL_DOWN);
    mgos_gpio_set_mode(pin_button, MGOS_GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    mgos_gpio_enable_int(pin_button);
    mgos_gpio_set_int_handler(pin_button, MGOS_GPIO_INT_EDGE_POS, gpio_int_cb, NULL);

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd check that the switch is actually working when pressed with a volt-meter.  Also check that pin_button should be 5 (I couldn't find any documentation between pin number and physical pin).  Also I'd install the handler before enabling it (avoid the unlikely but possible race condition of unhandled interrupt because the handler isn't installed yet when enabled).  You could always just test by reading current values on the pin to see if it ever changes.

Comment: @Fred. The diagram was for reference... I was using GPIO16 which unfortunatelly cannot be used with interrupts

Answer (score 1):

ESP8266 GPIO16 cannot be configured with interrupts. From the ESP8266 
[technical reference](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/esp8266-technical_reference_en_0.pdf):

> 5. GPIO16 Related APIs Different from other IO interfaces, GPIO16(XPD_DCDC) belongs to the RTC module instead of the general GPIO
>      module. It can be used to wake up the chip during deep-sleep; it can
>      be configured to input or output mode; **but it cannot trigger the IO
>      interrupt.**